# Combining Terraform module output to pass to another module

Tags: terraform

I'm creating Azure subnets azurerm_subnet using a module and have the following outputs declared in the module.

```
output "id" {
  description = "The id of the newly created Subnet"
  value       = azurerm_subnet.subnet.id
}
output "name" {
  description = "The id of the newly created Subnet"
  value       = azurerm_subnet.subnet.name
}

output "address_prefixes" {
  description = "The address prefixes of the newly created Subnet"
  value       = azurerm_subnet.subnet.address_prefixes
}
```

If for example I have created 2 subnets and want to pass both of these to another Network security group module how can I combine them together. I've tried merge, concat (Expects a set and toset doesn't seem to help) and zipmap all unsuccessfully. When I merge like below

```
output "subnets-combined" {
value = merge(module.subnet_01,module.subnet_02)
}
```

the output only contains subnet_02, presumably because of the following statement from the Terraform documentation

> If more than one given map or object defines the same key or attribute, then the one that is later in the argument sequence takes precedence.

This confuses me as all the output values should be distinct. How can I resolve this to create combined set of any number of subnets that I can reference by name?

Comment: What is your expected output type? Is it something like `["subnet_id_01", "subnet_id_02"]`

Comment: I'm looking to create a new map which contains the subnet names & address spaces. Or to be honest so long as I can retrieve the address space using the name I don't mind, I'm not a TF expert so open to suggestions.

something like the below

subnet_01 10.0.0.0/24
subnet_02 10.0.16.0/24

Answer (score 1):

Normally, `address_prefixes` attribute will be in `list of string` type and if you want to combine two different subnet resource's attribute value, you can make use of the `concat` function as below

```
concat(azurerm_subnet.example.address_prefixes, azurerm_subnet.sample.address_prefixes)
tolist([
  "10.0.2.0/24",
  "10.0.3.0/24",
])
```

`merge` function supports only `maps` and `objects`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I did try something similar to this but I need to be able to reference the subnets by name so would need the name property included also. I tried zipmap using address_prefixes and name to create a new map but ran into issues because name is a single string whereas address_prefixes is a list.

Comment: Alright, could you please be more specific on your expected output? What are all the attribute values you need in which type?

Comment: I just need "name" as a string and "address_prefixes" either as a list of strings or just a string containing the first entry from the list. Both are declared as outputs in the Subnet module.

Answer (score 0):

`module.subnet_01` and `module.subnet_02` are references to instances of the entire module. You need to reference specific values that the module outputs.

Something like this:

```
output "subnets-combined" {
    value = merge(module.subnet_01.address_prefixes, module.subnet_02.address_prefixes)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I need to be able to reference them by name so this won't help I don't beleive.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured this out, I created the below object combining the outputs from the various subnets

```
locals{
vnet_01_subnets = {
    sub_sql = {
      name = module.subnet_sub_sql_01.name
      address_prefix = module.subnet_sub_sql_01.address_prefixes[0]
    },
    sub_app = {
      name = module.subnet_sub_app_01.name
      address_prefix = module.subnet_sub_app_01.address_prefixes[0]
    },
    sub_web = {
      name = module.subnet_sub_web_01.name
      address_prefix = module.subnet_sub_web_01.address_prefixes[0]
    }
  }
 }
```

I then pass this into my module and can easily reference the subnets by the keys and retrieve either the name or address prefix.